# How to read HttpResponse in Android?

Tags: java, php, android, apache, http

I am trying to upload a audio file to my webserver. But don't know how to read the the response. Here is the very simplified test.php:

```
<?php 
  echo 'I want to see this in the Toast'; 
?>
```

fff And here is my onClick that must send the file to the webserver and get a response:

```
public void send(View v){
        Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("http").authority("sub.domain.nl").path("test.php")
                .appendQueryParameter("action", "sendMessage")
                .appendQueryParameter("idto", "18")
                .appendQueryParameter("idfrom", "36")
                .appendQueryParameter("type", "audio")
                .build();
        String urlString = uri.toString();
        new SendAudioTask().execute(urlString);
    }


    private class SendAudioTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                    "/audio.3gpp");

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                        new FileInputStream(file), -1);
                reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                reqEntity.setChunked(true); 
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                publishProgress(1);
            }
            return response.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dev message: = " + values[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Result.toString() in the onPostExecute() is

> org.apache.http.message.basicHttpRespons@43b4cc68

If toString() is the right way to read the response. What is wrong with my code? My code doesn't execute the publishProgress.

Comment: Why not use a lib, like okhttp or retrofit?

Comment: HttpResponse.toString() Isn't overloaded so is the base toString() for an object returning the classname and hash code. Use HttpResponse.getEntity() to get the data.

Comment: @zsolt.kocsi : Thx i will try the Libs, maybe later.

Comment: You should be aware that [HttpClient is not supported for Android](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) any more. [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) is a great alternative library

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
String result = convertStreamToString(is);

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
return response.toString();
```

to

```
return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

So what `getEntity()` does,

```
getEntity()
```

> Obtains the message entity of this response, if any.